# What causes Hibernate infinite loop at EntityType.java:677?

Tags: hibernate, infinite-loop

Running Hibernate 4.3.5, I get an infinite loop here, leading to a StackOverflowError:

```
org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType(EntityType.java:677)
```

The method in question is:

```
public final Type getIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType(Mapping factory) throws MappingException {
    if ( isReferenceToPrimaryKey() || uniqueKeyPropertyName == null ) {
        return getIdentifierType(factory);
    }
    else {
        Type type = factory.getReferencedPropertyType( getAssociatedEntityName(), uniqueKeyPropertyName );
        if ( type.isEntityType() ) {
            type = ( ( EntityType ) type).getIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType( factory );
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

Has anyone run into this issue before or know what causes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I had created two one-to-one relationships on either end:

```
<one-to-one name="payment" property-ref="invoice" lazy="proxy" />
<one-to-one name="invoice" property-ref="payment" lazy="proxy" />
```

Sends Hibernate into an infinite loop. I'll see if there is a bug report on this on Hibernate, because it would not seem impossible to add a check for this and a better error message.

Replacing one end of the relationship with:

```
<many-to-one name="payment" column="payment_id" unique="true" lazy="proxy" />
```

Fixed the problem.